# Ignite data afinnity for 2 caches

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I have two ignite caches:

```
public interface Entity1{ 
    Entity2 e2();
}

public interface Entity2{ }

IgniteCache<String, Entity1> e1s;
IgniteCache<String, Entity2> e2s;
//...
```

The reason I do exactly this is to process persons and companies separately, so I don't have to "lock the world" when processing only persons or companies.

As long as `Entity1 <-----> Entity2` is one-to-one I would like to deploy this caches the way so `Entity1 e1;` and `e1.e2()` are always on the same node.

I read about [***data to data Affinity***](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocate-data-with-data), but this is about the same cache, not two caches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not matter whether you have one cache or multiple caches. As long as the affinity function used is the same (or default) and the number of partitions is the same (or default), the affinity mapping in Apache Ignite will be the same.

Comment: But what is the parition? Is there some different between partition and shard concepts?

Comment: BTW, I read the documentation. How can I plug affinity function into my cluster?

Comment: More info on partitioning: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes

Comment: @St.Antario this documentation explains how to tweak or plugin an affinity function: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#affinity-function

Comment: Plus, an affinity function is set via `CacheConfiguration.setAffinity(affinityFunction)` method. So, just pass it to your cache configuration.